# while not equal in PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string `$number` with values like `1.00`, `2.000` or `0.000` and have to execute code while `$number` is not equal to `0.000`.

I have Perl syntax like:

```
while( ! ($number=~ /^0.00(.*)/)){
```

How do I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: Why don't you just compare ((float)$number == 0) ? In fact, even $number == 0 or just !$number will probably work.

Comment: Your regular expression treats 0.00999 as a loop terminator. But -0.00555 is not. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 4):

Use `preg_match`:

```
while (! preg_match('/^0\.00(.*)/', $number)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there something wrong with:

```
while (ceil($number)) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Rounding up to the nearest int and evaluating as a boolean should so the same job, and should also be considerably more efficient than firing up the Regex engine for every iteration...

Comment: I agree that this is more efficient than using regex, but your condition will be incorrect for a number like `0.001`; the question is a bit unclear about what exact values are and aren't allowed and what values he has and doesn't have.  At least he got a chance to learn how to use php regex.

Comment: @tandu: it's pointless learning how to use a tool when it is entirely the wrong tool for the job. If the OP continues to perform numeric comparisons using regular expressions then their code base will be a maintenance nightmare (and most likely end up on http://thedailywtf.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a job for regular expressions!

```
while ((float)$number) {
    // execute code
}
```